# Netcat exit on network disconnection

Tags: logging, connection, exit, netcat

I've got a netcat session that connects to a remote host and saves the stream to a logfile. This is the command:

> /bin/nc 192.168.0.170 5003 >> output.log

Unfortunately, if the network connection drops the session does not close and netcat will not exit. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-w <timeout>` option.

Comment: Unfortunately this is only a connection timeout that has no effect if the connection is already established..

Comment: perhaps a difference between versions: `-w` does have the desired effect on Linux http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc

Comment: you are right!!!

from man of the linux machine:
-w secs      timeout for connects and final net reads

from man of my mac
-w timeout  If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout seconds, then the connection is silently closed.

thank you!